# Is header with string keyword new in PHP?

Tags: php, header, facebook-php-sdk

In one of YouTube tutorial I came across this

```
header( string: 'location: login.php' );
```

It issues a syntax error on ':' for me but works fine for him. This works fine for me without 'string:' but wants to know the reason.

This code is used for FB login plugin in this tutorial.
Here's the link
https://youtu.be/1DgzTWr3F2I

19:00 min

My PHP version is 5.6.24

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That `string:` is just an IDE helper to tell you that the parameter expected is called `string`, it's not actually in the code.

Let me guess, is the tutorial person using IntelliJ Idea or PhpStorm? [They implemented it this year](https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2017/03/new-in-phpstorm-2017-1-parameter-hints/)

About the second error, the `->` sign must not have spaces between the method and the object.

Comment: Yes he is using phpstorm. Thanks. Do you have the answer for the second part

Comment: Edited with it.